# Replace hex char by a different random one (awk possible?)

Tags: bash, awk, replace, hexdump, xxd

have a mac address and I need to replace only one hex char (one at a very specific position) by a different random one (it must be different than the original). I have it done in this way using xxd and it works:

```
#!/bin/bash
mac="00:00:00:00:00:00" #This is a PoC mac address obviously :)
different_mac_digit=$(xxd -p -u -l 100 < /dev/urandom  | sed "s/${mac:10:1}//g" | head -c 1)
changed_mac=${mac::10}${different_mac_digit}${mac:11:6}
echo "${changed_mac}" #This echo stuff like 00:00:00:0F:00:00
```

The problem for my script is that using `xxd` means another dependency... I want to avoid it (not all Linux have it included by default). I have another workaround for this using `hexdump` command but using it I'm at the same stage... But my script already has a mandatory `awk` dependency, so... Can this be done using `awk`? I need an `awk` master here :) Thanks.

Comment: Sorry not clear. Can you clarify what are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to change one digit of a mac address. I need that specific position and I need to replace it by another random different hex char. And I need to do it using awk if possible inestead of using in the way I already have it done. Execute the poc and you'll see

Comment: Changing mac address at a specified position is fine but is generating random string by calling `xxd` also a requirement?

Comment: A different char is a requirement... but i'm trying to avoid the use of xxd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `xxd` or `hexdump`. `urandom` will also generate nubmers that match the encodings of the digits and letters used to represent hexadecimal numbers, therefore you can just use

```
old="${mac:10:1}"
different_mac_digit=$(tr -dc 0-9A-F < /dev/urandom | tr -d "$old" | head -c1)
```

Of course, you can replace your whole script with an `awk` script too. The following GNU `awk` script will replace the 11th symbol of each line with a random hexadecimal symbol different from the old one. With `<<< macaddress` we can feed `macaddress` to its stdin without having to use `echo` or something like that.

```
awk 'BEGIN { srand(); pos=11 } {
  old=strtonum("0x" substr($0,pos,1))
  new=(old + 1 + int(rand()*15)) % 16
  print substr($0,1,pos-1) sprintf("%X",new) substr($0,pos+1)
}' <<< 00:00:00:00:00:00
```

The trick here is to add a random number between 1 and 15 (both inclusive) to the digit to be modified. If we end up with a number greater than 15 we wrap around using the modulo operator `%` (`16` becomes `0`, `17` becomes `1`, and so on). That way the resulting digit is guaranteed to be different from the old one.

However, the same approach would be shorter if written completely in bash.

```
mac="00:00:00:00:00:00"
old="${mac:10:1}"
(( new=(16#"$old" + 1 + RANDOM % 15) % 16 ))
printf %s%X%s\\n "${mac::10}" "$new" "${mac:11}"
```

"One-liner" version:

```
mac=00:00:00:00:00:00
printf %s%X%s\\n "${mac::10}" "$(((16#${mac:10:1}+1+RANDOM%15)%16))" "${mac:11}"
```

Comment: @OscarAkaElvis Forgot about one requirement. Wait till I edit.

Comment: You need to add a check that the new digit is different from the original one

Comment: Yeah, sometimes it prints 00:00:00:00:00:00 what I want to avoid... i need a digit different than the original "0" in this case

Comment: srand() is not very random. Needs to have a better seed than time of day. otherwise multiple calls in quick succession will get the same result

Comment: @OscarAkaElvis Fixed the problem.

Comment: @jhnc What do you suggest? Initializing `srand` with `$RANDOM` from the shell?

Comment: yes, `-v seed=$RANDOM` and `srand(seed)` should help with randomness. Or `-v seed=$(date +%N)` or somesuch

Comment: This seems to work fine... in oneliner `mac="00:00:00:00:00:00";old="${mac:10:1}";(( new=(16#"$old" + 1 + $RANDOM % 15) % 16 ));printf %s%X%s\\n "${mac::10}" "$new" "${mac:11}"`

Comment: @OscarAkaElvis Glad to hear that. If you want to use it as a "one-liner" you can boil it down a bit, see edited answer.

Comment: Yeah i have it working flawlessly in oneliner... thanks so much

Comment: `new=(old + 1 + int(rand()*15)) % 16` - nice! You should mention that `strtonum()` is gawk-only.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this may work with seed value from `$RANDOM`:

```
mac="00:00:00:00:00:00"
awk -v seed=$RANDOM 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS=":"; srand(seed) } {
   s="0"
   while ((s = sprintf("%x", rand() * 16)) == substr($4, 2, 1))
   $4 = substr($4, 1, 1) s
} 1' <<< "$mac"
```

```
00:00:00:03:00:00
```

Inside while loop we continue until hex digit is not equal to `substr($4, 2, 1)` which 2nd char of 4th column.

Comment: Wait... this is not working if you set mac as "11:11:11:11:11:11", it is not printing the mac with only one char modified... it prints "11:11:11:03:11:11" but it should be "11:11:11:13:11:11"

Answer (score 1):

bash has printf builtin and a random function (if you trust it):

```
different_mac_digit() {
    new=$1
    while [[ $new = $1 ]]; do
        new=$( printf "%X" $(( RANDOM%16 )) )
    done
    echo $new
}
```

Invoke with the character to be replaced as argument.

Comment: This could be... but I'll wait for some oneliner solution if possible. Thanks, I already upvoted

Answer (score 1):

Another awk:

```
$ awk -v n=11 -v s=$RANDOM '                # set n to char # you want to replace
BEGIN { FS=OFS="" }{                        # each char is a field
    srand(s)                                
    while((r=sprintf("%x",rand()*16))==$n);  
    $n=r
}1' <<< $mac
```

Output:

```
00:00:00:07:00:00
```

or oneliner:

```
$ awk -v n=11 -v s=$RANDOM 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=""}{srand(s);while((r=sprintf("%x",rand()*16))==$n);$n=r}1' <<< $mac
```

Comment: yeah, another great solution using awk. upvoted, thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
$ mac="00:00:00:00:00:00"
$ awk -v m="$mac" -v p=11 'BEGIN{srand(); printf "%s%X%s\n", substr(m,1,p-1), int(rand()*15-1), substr(m,p+1)}'
00:00:00:01:00:00
$ awk -v m="$mac" -v p=11 'BEGIN{srand(); printf "%s%X%s\n", substr(m,1,p-1), int(rand()*15-1), substr(m,p+1)}'
00:00:00:0D:00:00
```

And to ensure you get a different digit than you started with:

```
$ awk -v mac="$mac" -v pos=11 'BEGIN {
    srand()
    new = old = toupper(substr(mac,pos,1))
    while (new==old) {
        new = sprintf("%X", int(rand()*15-1))
    }
    print substr(mac,1,pos-1) new substr(mac,pos+1)
}'
00:00:00:0D:00:00
```